# Generating timeuuids based on old timestamps cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am porting in data from an old postgres system onto cassandra. How do I create TimeUUIDs based on existing timestamps? I want to use existing timestamps as the sorting key. Or am I better off storing the exact timestamp instead of generating the TimeUUID?

Answer (score 0):

CQL3 provides functions for converting a timestamp into a UUID, these are called [minTimeuuid and maxTimeuuid](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
   WHERE t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000')
   AND t < minTimeuuid('2013-02-02 10:00+0000')
```

If you are using a datastax driver like the [java-driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) there should be a utility class like [UUIDs](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html) which provides capabilities for converting between TimeUUIDs and timestamps.